# How I can use the mean value theorem in this problem?

Tags: calculus

Use the Mean Value Theorem to estimate the value of $\sqrt{80}$.

and

how should we take $f(x)$?

Thanks in advance.

Regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to estimate a value of $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$, so that's a decent place to start. The mean value theorem says that there's an $a \in (80, 81)$ such that
$$
\frac{f(81) - f(80)}{81 - 80} = f'(a).
$$
I don't know what $a$ is, but you know $f(81)$ and you hopefully know how to write down $f'$. How small can $f'(a)$ be?

Comment: Thanks. When I do that, I get:
$$\sqrt {80}  = 9 - \frac{1}{{2\sqrt a }}$$
So what do I do next?
Would you give values ​​to the number $a$?

Comment: keep in mind $80<a<81$

Comment: Oh, so what the problem ends there?
  Is it only adds $80<a<81$ anything else?

Comment: @mathsalomon I waffled a bit on that point. My feeling is that this is a very optimistic estimate: get an upper bound on what $\sqrt{80}$ could be. It turns out to be a decent approximation (to within three decimal places) of the actual value. I don't see anything else to grab onto -- do you?

Comment: I guess another clue is that evaluating $1/(2\sqrt{a})$ at anything other than $81$ is going to be pretty wild.

Comment: You could make a very crude estimate and say that $\sqrt{a} >8,$ which would (using also $\sqrt{a} <9$) that $$9 -  \frac{1}{16} < \sqrt{80} < 9 - \frac{1}{18}.$$ Or a more informed original guess might have been that $\sqrt{a} > 8.5,$ giving   $$ 9 - \frac{1}{17} < \sqrt{80} < 9 - \frac{1}{18},$$ placing $\sqrt{80}$ in an interval of length $\frac{1}{306}.$

Comment: excelent!! thanks so much =)